# Clean install of Ubuntu 14.10 hangs

Tags: 14.10

I am trying to do a "clean" installation of Ubuntu 14.10 but the process gets part of the way and then hangs. At first I thought it might be a problem with the DVD so I burned another but that didn't work either. This is what I have done:

When the installer got to the point where it asks where to install it and gave various options, I chose "Something else".
I then told it to install it on /dev/sda1 (which already has Ubuntu 14.04) and to format the partition with a mount point as /
I also specified that /dev/sda2 was  to be the /home directory
The installation carried on for a while and then hung.

I have made several attempts with both DVDs but it appears to hang at the same place (formatting the partition before copying the files) each time with either DVD.

What am I doing wrong??

I am wondering if I should have formatted the partition first, using gparted.

I used Ubuntu 14.04 to download the .iso file and Brasero to burn it

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem on older notebook, but the installation went to the end and hung. Although if Your case is related I suggest making sure You have enough `RAM` and define `swap` space - at the same step as installation target (`swap` for temporary storage during installation and work of system in the future).

Also I would'n concern the installation about `sda2` as `/home`, You can do that afterwards, just don't format or change anything You don't need to.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is any bug with parted or mkfs,
so what I did is create partition again and using terminal (Ctrl-Alt+F1) did a mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdaX, then rebooted and started installation again without formating any partition and installation succeded.

Comment: I had the same issue, and when I did the mkfs.ext4 it said that it looked like a dos partition and did I want to continue. I'm assuming that same question is being asked in the installer, but it isn't responding.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new partition table on the drive you want to install Ubuntu on and make a completely new filesystem. I had an issue were it would crash and doing that fixed it for me, just make sure you backup any important data. Also if possible try installing using a USB instead of a DVD.